# Kendo Grid resizing column does not show resize handle of their header cells

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following kendo grid in ASP.NET Core. The grid is using `BindTo` method to bind grid to model

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<AccountGridModel>()
        .Name("MyGrid")                        
        .Columns(col =>
        {
            col.Bound(p => p.AccountID).ClientTemplate("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"mt-acct\" class=\"mt-act\" />").Width(30).Title(" ");
            col.Bound(p => p.AccountNumber).ClientTemplate("<a href=\"#= ExternalAccountLink #\" target=\"_blank\">#= AccountNumber #</a>").Width(250).Title("Account Number");         
            col.Bound(p => p.AccountType).Width(200).Title("Account Type");     
            col.Bound(p => p.AccountDescription).Width(200).Title("Account Description");
        })
        .AutoBind(true)
        .BindTo(Model.Accounts)
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable(sortable => sortable
            .AllowUnsort(true)
            .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
 )
```

I have set width on all columns and enabled Resizing. Idea is once it is set the users can resize columns by dragging the edges (resize handles) of their header cells.

**ISSUE**
1> When grid renders i cannot see resize handle when i hove over the column edges.
2> How do i set PageSize? Grid is not using Ajax. In Ajax Call we can set pagesize like 
        `.DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().PageSize(50))`
   How do i use the default page size here

Answer (score 1):

For issue 1 - not seeing the resize handle, do you have the kendo CSS styles included (either in your layout or this page)?

For issue 2: Even though you're binding to local data, you can still set the PageSize on the DataSource (just set ServerOperation to false), see the code below from [the example here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/local-data-binding).

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerOperation(false))
```

Comment: For issue 1, kendo css are included in layout page but still now working. Issue 2 is fixed with your suggestion

Comment: Does the column resize work even though the hover resize icon doesn't show? Interesting, maybe search to see if there is any code doing anything with k-resize-handle like this question does https://stackoverflow.com/q/57617740/493557  total guess. Does it work in a different browser?

Comment: No column resize does not work and  i also do not see resize icon

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Kendo? It looks like there was a bug back in 2017 - this doesn't apply to you does it? https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/3623